# CSV row splitting

Tags: python, csv

I am working on implementation of a data mining  algorithm  in python. I have a large csv file which I am using as the input file to get the itemsets. I want to split the csv file into rows through program. Can someone tell how to make it possible?

Comment: see Pandas library, more precisely read_csv()

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
pd.read_csv(file_name,sep='rows separator')
```

see http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html for details.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the rows are delimited by new-lines and that columns are delimited by commas. In which case just python already knows how to read it line by line which in your case means row by row. Then each row can be split where there are commas.

```
item_sets=[] #Will put the data in here

with open(filename, "r") as file: # open the file
  for data_row in file:   #get data one row at a time
     # split up the row into columns, stripping whitespace from each one
     # and store it in item_sets
     item_sets.append(  [x.strip() for x in data_row.split(",")] )
```

Comment: There are many implementations for that.. why write it again?

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv

with open('eggs.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
    spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|')
    for row in spamreader:
        print row
```

will printout all rows of a csv file as lists
I assume pandas impelmentation of `read_csv` is more efficient, but the `csv` module is built into python so if you don't want any dependencies, you can use it.